# ALT + TAB Windows in All Workspaces in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, unity, 20.04, shortcut-keys, workspaces

When using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I was able to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> through applications in all workspaces. Whenever I would select an application that was open only in a workspace different from the current one, it would switch to that workspace.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20 LTS, I have noticed that it only shows apps that are open in the currently selected workspace.

How can I restore the former behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**The application switcher and the window switcher**

In Gnome Desktop, which is used on the standard Ubuntu desktop, there is an application switcher and windows switcher.

The *application switcher* switches between applications. Selecting an application brings all windows to the foreground. However, if you wait a little while an application with multiple windows is selected, a pane will appear showing individual windows. With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key_above_Tab</kbd>, you can then select a window and bring only that to the front.

[image]

The *window switcher* is more traditional and shows the individual open windows.

[image]

In default Gnome Shell, only the application switcher is used. It is bound to both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Ubuntu currently binds the traditional window switcher to the former, and the application switcher to the latter.

The application switcher by default switches through applications on all desktops. The window switcher by default switches through applications on the current desktop only.

**Changing keybindings**

Keybindings for the application switcher and the window switchers can be set in  *Keyboard Shortcuts* under "Settings", section "Navigation". Look for *Switch applications* and *Switch windows*.

**Changing scope**

You can change the scope of the window switcher from *current workspace only* to *all workspaces* with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false
```

You can change the scope of the application switcher from *all workspaces* to *current workspace only* with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

Use the same commands, replacing `set` with `reset` and leaving out the argument (e.g. `false`) to reset the setting to default. You can also use the graphical tool `dconf-editor` (not installed by default) to change these settings.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed (on Debian 11)!

TL;DR: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true` will set `Alt+Tab` to only cycle through applications in the *current workspace*.

Comment: works on fedora too

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut was changed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, which is suboptimal for a lot of people who have developed muscle memory for the classic <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you would like the previous functionality back, run this in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
```

Done and done

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to retain both shortcuts, while still having the old school as ALT + TAB?

Comment: I have discovered that Super + Tab retained the old behavior. That should do it.

Comment: ALT + TAB - switch window,
Super + TAB - switch application